# T SQL select top 10 loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

I have a table that has 10 unique values in column A and many more different unique values in column B (one to many), as well as an amount column at the end (column C)  I'm looking to loop through each of the 10 unique values of column A and return only the top 10 values of column B for each value in Column A (using column C to determine the top values) and then take the top 100 resulting values of column B.

What's the easiest way to write this in SQL?

Comment: welcome to SO. No one gonna write for you unless you show what you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking loops and sql, you're looking in the wrong place. There's pretty much always a way to write a set-based query that avoids loops, runs faster, and is easier to write and maintain. Case in point:

```
SELECT t1.[A], t2.[B], t2.[C]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [A] FROM [table]) t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 10 [B], [C] FROM [Table] t0 WHERE t0.[A] = t1.[A] ORDER BY [C] DESC
) t2
```